# Trying to claim website URL for Facebook Instant Articles, but receive fb:pages error

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-instant-articles

**The fb:pages tag on the url doesn't contain this page's id. The url has
fb:pages tag but they don't have this page's id. Please work with your
developers / webmaster to add this tag to your website.**

On a Wordpress site, using a child theme. I copied the header.php file from the parent and uploaded it to the child theme, and placed the following code within the  tags in the **header.php** file:

```
<meta property="fb:pages" content="#############" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
```

I have troubleshooted this issue in all the recommended ways, including clearing my browser and Wordpress cache, and still continue to get this error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Tested this on a different site I am working on (non-Wordpress) and it worked perfectly, so likely has something to do with Wordpress or other plugins that are installed, but still am not sure where to look.

Comment: Do those tags show up in the generated HTML source code? Have you checked your OG tags/refreshed the cache using the debug tool?

Comment: I actually was able to claim the url just by disabling some plugins temporarily, and then reactivating them. I think it might have been a conflict with the "Coming Soon" plugin.

Comment: But thank you for these ideas, because I had no idea that I needed to us OG tags (blog isn't set up yet), so this will come in handy in the future.

Comment: Just wanted to comment on this because I had a very similar issue (wp too). Tried a lot of stuff but at the end, placing both meta tags (fb and og) on top of the other tags in the <head> worked for me.